# Optimal way to drawing scenes on top of each others

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to draw scenes on top of each other, my way of doing so in **OpenGL** was to draw each scene and then clear the depth stencil and then draw the next scene.

For **Vulkan** world, if we want to translate my previous way, I have to start a render-pass and then draw each scene and then clear the depth-stencil (vkCmdClearAttachments) and then draw the next scene and end the render-pass. But several questions come in my mind:

- Is there any better strategy for it? (e.g. starting new-render pass for each scene.)
- I found the `vkCmdClearAttachments` but I'm not sure that it needs synchronization with previous and next commands or not?

Comment: "*I'm not sure that it needs synchronization with previous and next commands or not?*" The first rule of Vulkan: if it is accessing memory someone else accesses (unless both accesses are reads), it *always* needs synchronization. Obviously there are many cases where this isn't true, but it's always a good default assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "optimal" way to do this, whether in Vulkan or OpenGL, is to partition your depth buffer into two regions: one for each scene. You use the [viewport transform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Viewport_Transform) for partitioning the depth buffer. One scene would get the [0.5, 1] range, while the next would get the [0, 0.5] range. `glDepthRange` is what you would use to set this in OpenGL, and the `min/maxDepth` fields of `VkViewport` handle the similar transform in Vulkan.

If for some reason you can't partition your depth buffer (perhaps because both scenes need the extra precision of small floating-point values up-close), then which alternative is more optimal will almost certainly depend on the underlying hardware. On a tile-based renderer, I would imagine that `vkCmdClearAttachments` is not good news as far as performance is concerned. But for a traditional renderer, such a clear call is hardly a performance problem, and the cost of having to begin a new renderpass would be the main thing you would use.

Comment: Why would `vkCmdClearAttachments` necessarily be bad in a tiled renderer?  Assuming the attachment isn't preserved _between_ render passes, the driver should have all the information it needs to collapse to a 'clear this tile' operation  and keep the attachment as a whole "virtual".

Comment: @Jherico: Because, if you clear the depth buffer, that means you have to have actually *performed* all of the per-fragment operations on the previous stuff. Which means you have to rasterize everything within a tile in-order. Which is something that some TBRs don't do. And even those that do will sometimes optimize this by essentially doing a depth pre-pass, then going back and executing the particular fragment shaders for those fragments that actually get seen.

Comment: Depth partitioning is not a good thing, because I loose precision and z fighting will appear, and add design complexity to my code, so I come to this conclusion to begin a new render-pass for each scene.

Comment: @NicolBolas wouldn't using a set of lazily allocated transient depth buffer attachments allow you to accomplish the same thing without an explicit clear, depth partitioning or a new renderpass?  You'd just cycle through the depth attachments for each 'partitioned' scene.